# possible to use media library with independent set of files in plugin?

Tags: uploads, media-library

I'm looking to have a page located in the Wordpress admin backend powered by a custom plugin have access to upload and manage previously uploaded images, essentially using the media library.  But I am looking to customize that environment by:

- having a completely separate set of images (this set doesn't affect the main media library and is its own set only available inside this single custom backend page)
- save/store images in a different custom folder than the normal uploads

I would really like to avoid having to install another third party plugin for this if possible, as the site this is in is already quite bloated with plugins.

Anyone know of a solid solution or if this is possible with Wordpress' native media library?